# Is this code for determining if a circle and line SEGMENT intersects correct?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, collision-detection

It's apparently very hard to find the answer to whether a line *segment* and circle intersect. For example, if you google you'll find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm) and even the top two answers seem wrong.

The accepted answer has a comment saying: `This seems to compute the intersection of a circle with a line, not a segment` Scroll down to the next answer and you'll find another comment saying `Isn't this answer in incomplete? It finds whether a circle and line intersect, not a line segment`.

I've then tried to search for a function for determining if just a *segment* intersects a circle, but to no avail. The best I could find is a [pseudocode explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053697/962155).

I've tried to adapt his code and while it seems to work, it seems overly verbose and I'm not sure if my implementation is correct. I'm asking whether or not this is correct and if it is, is there indeed no better way of determining this? What is the ideal way of determining if a line segment and circle intersects? Please note, I only need to know *if* they intersect, not where they intersect.

I've provided a full demo reproduction below so you can also visualize it.

```js
function lineSegmentIntersectsCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy, r) {
  let deltaX = x2 - x1;
  let deltaY = y2 - y1;

  let mag = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);

  let unitX = deltaX / mag;
  let unitY = deltaY / mag;

  let d = (cx - x1) * unitY - (cy - y1) * unitX;

  if (d < -r || d > r) { return false; }

  let x1CXDelta = x1 - cx;
  let y1CYDelta = y1 - cy;

  let x2CXDelta = x2 - cx;
  let y2CYDelta = y2 - cy;

  let pointOneWithinCircle = x1CXDelta * x1CXDelta + y1CYDelta * y1CYDelta < r * r;
  if (pointOneWithinCircle) { return true; }

  let pointTwoWithinCircle = x2CXDelta * x2CXDelta + y2CYDelta * y2CYDelta < r * r;
  if (pointTwoWithinCircle) { return true; }

  let foo = unitX * x1 + unitY * y1;
  let bar = unitX * cx + unitY * cy;
  let baz = unitX * x2 + unitY * y2;

  return (foo < bar && bar < baz) || (baz < bar && bar < foo); 
}

let ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

function drawCircle(xCenter, yCenter, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(xCenter, yCenter, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.stroke();
}

let circleX = 340;
let circleY = 250;
let circleR = 60;

let lineX1 = 50;
let lineY1 = 350;
let lineX2 = 285;
let lineY2 = 250;

draw = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#b2c7ef";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800); 

  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

  drawCircle(circleX, circleY, circleR);
  drawLine(lineX1, lineY1, lineX2, lineY2);
}

console.log(lineSegmentIntersectsCircle(lineX1, lineY1, lineX2, lineY2, circleX, circleY, circleR))

draw();
```

```css
canvas { display: flex; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: This seems to work as long as you consider the "completely inside" case to be "intersecting".

Comment: I do indeed desire that behavior. Okay, cool, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be a simpler to (1) compute the line-disk intersection, which is either empty, a point, or a line segment (2) test whether the intersection intersects the line segment.

The points of the line are `((1-t) x1 + t x2, (1-t) y1 + t y2)` for all real `t`. Let `x(t) = (1-t) x1 + t x2 - cx` and `y(t) = (1-t) y1 + t y2 - cy`. The line-disk intersection is nonempty if and only if the polynomial `x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 - r^2 = 0` has real roots `t1 <= t2`. In this case, the line-disk intersection is all `t` in `[t1, t2]`. The line segment is all `t` in `[0, 1]`. The two intersect if and only if `t1 <= 1` and `t2 >= 0`.

Computing `t1` and `t2` requires a square root, which we can avoid. Let `a, b, c` be such that `x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 - r^2 = a t^2 + b t + c`. We have `t1 + t2 = -b/a` and `t1 t2 = c/a`.

- The roots `t1` and `t2` are real if and only if `b^2 - 4 a c >= 0`.
- The condition `t1 <= 1` is false if and only if `t1 - 1 > 0` and `t2 - 1 > 0`, which in turn is true if and only if `(t1 - 1) + (t2 - 1) > 0` and `(t1 - 1) (t2 - 1) > 0`, which is equivalent to `-b/a - 2 > 0` and `c/a + b/a + 1 > 0`. Since `a > 0`, this simplifies to `-b > 2 a` and `c + b + a > 0`.
- The condition `t2 >= 0` is false if and only if `t1 < 0` and `t2 < 0`, which in turn is true if and only if `t1 + t2 = -b/a < 0` and `t1 t2 = c/a > 0`. Since `a > 0`, this simplifies to `b > 0` and `c > 0`.

Implementation in Javascript.

```
function lineSegmentIntersectsCircleOptimized(x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy, r) {
  let x_linear = x2 - x1;
  let x_constant = x1 - cx;
  let y_linear = y2 - y1;
  let y_constant = y1 - cy;
  let a = x_linear * x_linear + y_linear * y_linear;
  let half_b = x_linear * x_constant + y_linear * y_constant;
  let c = x_constant * x_constant + y_constant * y_constant - r * r;
  return (
    half_b * half_b >= a * c &&
    (-half_b <= a || c + half_b + half_b + a <= 0) &&
    (half_b <= 0 || c <= 0)
  );
}

function lineSegmentIntersectsCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy, r) {
  let deltaX = x2 - x1;
  let deltaY = y2 - y1;

  let mag = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);

  let unitX = deltaX / mag;
  let unitY = deltaY / mag;

  let d = (cx - x1) * unitY - (cy - y1) * unitX;

  if (d < -r || d > r) {
    return false;
  }

  let x1CXDelta = x1 - cx;
  let y1CYDelta = y1 - cy;

  let x2CXDelta = x2 - cx;
  let y2CYDelta = y2 - cy;

  let pointOneWithinCircle =
    x1CXDelta * x1CXDelta + y1CYDelta * y1CYDelta < r * r;
  if (pointOneWithinCircle) {
    return true;
  }

  let pointTwoWithinCircle =
    x2CXDelta * x2CXDelta + y2CYDelta * y2CYDelta < r * r;
  if (pointTwoWithinCircle) {
    return true;
  }

  let foo = unitX * x1 + unitY * y1;
  let bar = unitX * cx + unitY * cy;
  let baz = unitX * x2 + unitY * y2;

  return (foo < bar && bar < baz) || (baz < bar && bar < foo);
}

function test() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    let x1 = Math.random();
    let y1 = Math.random();
    let x2 = Math.random();
    let y2 = Math.random();
    let cx = Math.random();
    let cy = Math.random();
    let r = Math.random();
    if (
      lineSegmentIntersectsCircle(x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy, r) !=
      lineSegmentIntersectsCircleOptimized(x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy, r)
    ) {
      console.log("bad");
      break;
    }
  }
}

test();
```

Comment: @RyanPeschel let me have a go at optimizing this one.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment because it initially said this was slightly slower but I re-ran the benchmark and it was slightly faster that time. But yeah that would be much appreciated regardless! It'd be nice to have an authoritative and maximally efficient answer available on Stackoverflow for a proper function that determines line segment + circle intersections, considering how hard it is to find at the moment.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much.

Comment: @RyanPeschel shaved some more multiplies.