# How to handle circles in geometric intersection

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Recently, I'm working on a programming assignment related to Geometric intersection. The problem is to count how many intersections can be formed with the following 4 elements:

1. Segment; 2) ray; 3) line；4) circle;

The link to the problem: [Portal](https://dsa.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/oj/problem.shtml?id=1646)
. If you cannot access it, there is the printable PDF: [Portal](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JK-ToXKfRmaR6IMg3x9sEBDa6tF7FHu2/view?usp=sharing)

I've figured out how to deal with line and ray, the way is visualized as the follows:

[Visualized image of handling line and ray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjL70.png)

In other words, we can preprocess them and treat them as special segments. But I have no idea of how to handle circles. The hint, Circle roads can be broken into a number of arcs, is still unclear to me.

Comment: Seems like a strange hint to me. The constraint should be achievable with a quadratic algorithm. I'd modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67117213/2144669) to count intersections.

Comment: Your question falls out of the scope of this site. We are not a homework factory. Write a program first.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would like to write a program, but I don't know how to modify B.O. algorithm, a kind of algorithm handling segment intersections, to ideal with cycles. I figured out how to use it handle line and ray, but cycle yet. I am stuck with it now.

Answer (score 1):

To intersect a circle with a line/ray/segment, you can move the circle to the origin and rotate so that the linear entity becomes horizontal at ordinate `h`.

Then the abscissas of the intersection with the line of support are given by `±√r²-h²`. You can easily check if these points belong to the useful part of the line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I'll take it into consideration as well. And I've came up with an idea of breaking a cycle into four quarters of arcs, and handle them in the same way as segments, but your proposal should a good way to check if a segment intersects with a cycle.

Comment: @fengkeyleaf: splitting the circle in arcs will not help, on the opposite. Because an arc can anyway be intersected once or twice.